# Python - Twisted client - check protocol.transport connection in ping loop

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, twisted, twisted.internet

I'm creating TCP client socket with Twisted. I need to check connection status in a loop interval in connectionMade method.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class ClientProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
       while not thread_obj.stopped.wait(10):
            print ('ping')
            self.transport.write(b'test') # Byte value
```

For check connection losing, i manually disconnect my network And I checked some variables after that as bellow:

```
print (self.connected)
print (self.transport.connector.state)
print (self.transport.connected)
print (self.transport.reactor.running)
print (self.transport.socket._closed)
print (self.factory.protocol.connected)
print (self._writeDissconnected)
```

But any variables value didn't change after disconnecting my network :(

**My question is:** which variables will be set when the connection lost? I mean  how can i check the connection status and if it's disconnect, how can i reconnect that?

Comment: What's the while loop doing inside `connectionMade`? Does it prevent `connectionMade` from ever returning?

Comment: @keturn Thanks for your attention, The loop inside `connectionMade` is for checking or pinging the connection and notify when the connection lost. This loop doesn't prevent from returning. but the values that i printed in question, never changed after disconnecting from server. i need to know how can i check the connection status and if it's disconnect, how can i reconnect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override `connectionLost` method to catch disconnection. 
[to official docs](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.1.0/api/twisted.internet.protocol.Protocol.html)

Edit about reconnection:
Reconnection mostly is a logical decision. You may want to add logic between 'connectionLost' and 'reconnect'.

Anyway,
You can use [ReconnectingClientFactory](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.1.0/core/howto/clients.html#reconnection) for better code.
ps: using factory pattern at reconnection is best way to keep code clean and smart.

```
class MyEchoClient(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        someFuncProcessingData(data)
        self.transport.write(b'test')

class MyEchoClientFactory(ReconnectingClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print 'Connected.'
        return MyEchoClient()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Lost connection.  Reason:', reason
        ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Connection failed. Reason:', reason
        ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionFailed(self, connector,
                                                     reason)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. you mean i don't need to check connection in interval loop?? And you mean if the connection lost, the `connectionLost` method will be call automatically ? if it's true, how i can reconnect that? it's better if you give me sample code or reference :)

Comment: Yes. exactly.Yo will forgot to use loops with twisted :D